# How do feed my bot contextn specific entities?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to build a Chatbot with LUIS.

The client side application knows all entities that are relevant to the current user. They are different for each user.

How can I teach these dynamic entities to the bot?

Alternatively I should I teach the bot about different generic entities like:

- A0,A1, ... ,AN
- B0,B1, ... ,BN
- C0,C1, ... ,CN
- ...

And then my application could replace the actual entity "" with "A1" before passing the message to the bot?

**Update1**:

- User 1 might say - "Show me a tiger", "Remove the cat", "Switch the dog with the mouse"
- User 2 would say - "Show me a car", "Remove the bike", "Switch the ship with the plane"

Comment: Can you give some examples of utterances that LUIS might receive? In theory, you should be able to create a simple entity, train it with enough utterance samples, then you should be able to get back what you need. You could have an entity for both the `private/relative to user` and for the `generic` entities. (If i'm following you correctly)

Comment: Added some above @DanaV